# Combining tabularx and longtable

Tags: tables

This is my first post so forgive me if I do something incorrectly.

I am trying to create a long table that goes over multiple pages but I don't want to lose the tabularx code that I've been using. In addition, I would like to shorten my first two columns (but still have them go over multiple rows if need be.

Any help would be appreciated and forgive me if this is a dumb question, I only started using Latex last week.

```
 \begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{Summary of Multipliers from the Literature}\label{Lit Summary table}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XXXX}
    \hline\hline
    \textbf{Study} & \textbf{Geographical Location and Level} & \textbf{Identification} & \textbf{Multiplier Result} \\ \hline \hline
        \citeA{nakamura2014fiscal} & US State Level & Instrumented on the fact that when national spending on the military rises by 1 percentage point of GDP in the US, different states, depending on their exposure to military spending, experience different levels of military build-up & 1.5 growing to 2.0 at zero lower bound \\ \hline
        \citeA{ramey2011identifying} & US Federal Level & Looked at the military build-up during significant wars throughout the 20\textsuperscript{th} century in the US &  0.6-1.2 \\ \hline \citeA{Barro} & US Federal Level & Spending multipliers are identified primarily from variations in defense spending, especially changes associated with buildups and aftermaths of wars. & 0.4-0.5 contemporaneously, 0.6-0.7 2 years later and if multiplier is permanent then this adds 0.1-0.2 to the multiplier  \\ \hline \citeA{auerbach} & US Federal Level & Extended SVAR approach & 0-0.5 in Expansion and 1.0-1.5 in Recession \\ \hline \citeA{fazzari2015state} & US State Level & Bayesian model comparison and generalized impulse response analysis to test for nonlinearities in the responses of output to government spending & 0.8 for states with low slack and 1.6 for states with high slack \\ \hline \citeA{Ramey2018} & US Federal Level & Analysed quarterly US data over a 120 year period using the local projection method developed by \citeA{Jorda} & 0.3-1.5 depending on the methodology and robustness check they used.  \\ \hline \citeA{shoag2010impact} & US State Level & Instrumented on the windfall gains that US states receive from investing public pension funds & Baseline multiplier over 2, rising to over 3 in times of economic slack \\ \hline \citeA{suarez2016estimating} & US County Level & Instrumented on Federal transfers to local counties due to changes in population forecasts between Census and Non-census years & 1.7-2 rising in counties experiencing economic slack \\ \hline \citeA{michaillat2014theory} & US Federal Level & Simple search-and-matching model to highlight the key economic forces of the multiplier & The multiplier doubles when unemployment rises from 5\% to 8\% \\ \hline \citeA{clemens2012} & US State Level & Instrumented on the variation in the strictness states' balanced budget requirements to determine the level as a means of measuring the level of spending cuts during a recession & 0.4 however it may be higher if states receive windfall funding \\ \hline \citeA{Ilzetzki} & 44 countries around the world \footnote{20 high-income and 44 low income} & SVAR approach on a novel dataset & High income countries tend to have a statistically significant positive fiscal multiplier while the opposite is true of developing countries and Investment in infrastructure could lead to a higher multiplier \\ \hline \citeA{acconcia2014mafia} & Italy Local Level & Looked at a situation when local governments were dismissed and public funding was severely reduced in Italy is response to being infiltrated by the mafia.   & 1.5 on impact, growing to 1.9 when dynamic effects are included. \\ \hline \citeA{fishback2015multiplier} & US State Level & Panel of annual Federal expenditure in each State during the 1930s & 0.96 when Federal transfer payments are excluded falling to 0.83 when they are included  \\ 
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What do you mean with ‘losing the tabularx code’?

Comment: You could use one of the following packages: `ltxtable`, `ltablex`, `xltabular`.

Comment: Bernard thank you for the welcome! I mean the functionality of it. Forgive me for not being clearer.

Comment: Leandriis, what code do I use (or replace) in my table once I use one of those packages?

Comment: in addition to the packages noted above which combine tabularx and longtable, you can (and I would as the author of both those packages) just use longtable. `tabularx` isn't doing anything very useful with a preamble of `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XXXX}` as you know in advance the column widths will be a quarter of textwidth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\def\citeA#1{}% For demo here
\begin{document}

\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{lp{3cm}XX}
\caption{Summary of Multipliers from the Literature}\label{Lit Summary table}\\ \hline\hline
\textbf{Study} & \textbf{Geographical Location and Level} & \textbf{Identification} & 
\textbf{Multiplier Result} \\ \hline \hline
\endfirsthead
\hline\hline
\textbf{Study} & \textbf{Geographical Location and Level} & \textbf{Identification} & 
\textbf{Multiplier Result} \\ \hline \hline
\endhead
\hline
\endfoot
\citeA{nakamura2014fiscal} & US State Level & Instrumented on the fact that when national spending on 
        the military rises by 1 percentage point of GDP in the US, different states, depending on their 
        exposure to military spending, experience different levels of military build-up & 1.5 growing to 2.0 
        at zero lower bound \\ \hline
        \citeA{ramey2011identifying} & US Federal Level & Looked at the military build-up during significant 
        wars throughout the 20\textsuperscript{th} century in the US &  0.6-1.2 \\ \hline \citeA{Barro} & US 
        Federal Level & Spending multipliers are identified primarily from variations in defense spending, 
        especially changes associated with buildups and aftermaths of wars. & 0.4-0.5 contemporaneously, 
        0.6-0.7 2 years later and if multiplier is permanent then this adds 0.1-0.2 to the multiplier  \\ 
        \hline \citeA{auerbach} & US Federal Level & Extended SVAR approach & 0-0.5 in Expansion and 1.0-1.5 
        in Recession \\ \hline \citeA{fazzari2015state} & US State Level & Bayesian model comparison and 
        generalized impulse response analysis to test for nonlinearities in the responses of output to 
        government spending & 0.8 for states with low slack and 1.6 for states with high slack \\ \hline 
        \citeA{Ramey2018} & US Federal Level & Analysed quarterly US data over a 120 year period using the 
        local projection method developed by \citeA{Jorda} & 0.3-1.5 depending on the methodology and 
        robustness check they used.  \\ \hline \citeA{shoag2010impact} & US State Level & Instrumented on the 
        windfall gains that US states receive from investing public pension funds & Baseline multiplier over 
        2, rising to over 3 in times of economic slack \\ \hline \citeA{suarez2016estimating} & US County 
        Level & Instrumented on Federal transfers to local counties due to changes in population forecasts 
        between Census and Non-census years & 1.7-2 rising in counties experiencing economic slack \\ \hline 
        \citeA{michaillat2014theory} & US Federal Level & Simple search-and-matching model to highlight the 
        key economic forces of the multiplier & The multiplier doubles when unemployment rises from 5\% to 
        8\% \\ \hline \citeA{clemens2012} & US State Level & Instrumented on the variation in the strictness 
        states' balanced budget requirements to determine the level as a means of measuring the level of 
        spending cuts during a recession & 0.4 however it may be higher if states receive windfall funding \\ 
        \hline \citeA{Ilzetzki} & 44 countries around the world \footnote{20 high-income and 44 low income} & 
        SVAR approach on a novel dataset & High income countries tend to have a statistically significant 
        positive fiscal multiplier while the opposite is true of developing countries and Investment in 
        infrastructure could lead to a higher multiplier \\ \hline \citeA{acconcia2014mafia} & Italy Local 
        Level & Looked at a situation when local governments were dismissed and public funding was severely 
        reduced in Italy is response to being infiltrated by the mafia.   & 1.5 on impact, growing to 1.9 
        when dynamic effects are included. \\ \hline \citeA{fishback2015multiplier} & US State Level & Panel 
        of annual Federal expenditure in each State during the 1930s & 0.96 when Federal transfer payments 
        are excluded falling to 0.83 when they are included  \\ 
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I highly appreciate the help but as I commented to leandriis post, Overleaf is not recognizing the xltabular package. Are you aware of something I can do to fix this?

Comment: Use the package `ltablex` instead and the default `tabularx` environment with the same `firsthead` and so on defionition as shown in my example.

Comment: Are you please able to give me an example of the code for this?

Comment: It works! Thank you so so much! You are a life saver!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a MWE using the `xltabular` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{apacite}

\begin{document}
    \begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{l>{\hsize=0.75\hsize}X>{\hsize=1.125\hsize}X>{\hsize=1.125\hsize}X}
    \caption{Summary of Multipliers from the Literature}\label{Lit Summary table}\\
    \hline\hline
    \textbf{Study} & \textbf{Geographical Location and Level} & \textbf{Identification} & \textbf{Multiplier Result} \\ \hline \hline 
    \endhead
        \citeA{nakamura2014fiscal} & US State Level & Instrumented on the fact that when national spending on the military rises by 1 percentage point of GDP in the US, different states, depending on their exposure to military spending, experience different levels of military build-up & 1.5 growing to 2.0 at zero lower bound \\ \hline
        \citeA{ramey2011identifying} & US Federal Level & Looked at the military build-up during significant wars throughout the 20\textsuperscript{th} century in the US &  0.6-1.2 \\ \hline \citeA{Barro} & US Federal Level & Spending multipliers are identified primarily from variations in defense spending, especially changes associated with buildups and aftermaths of wars. & 0.4-0.5 contemporaneously, 0.6-0.7 2 years later and if multiplier is permanent then this adds 0.1-0.2 to the multiplier  \\ \hline \citeA{auerbach} & US Federal Level & Extended SVAR approach & 0-0.5 in Expansion and 1.0-1.5 in Recession \\ \hline \citeA{fazzari2015state} & US State Level & Bayesian model comparison and generalized impulse response analysis to test for nonlinearities in the responses of output to government spending & 0.8 for states with low slack and 1.6 for states with high slack \\ \hline \citeA{Ramey2018} & US Federal Level & Analysed quarterly US data over a 120 year period using the local projection method developed by \citeA{Jorda} & 0.3-1.5 depending on the methodology and robustness check they used.  \\ \hline \citeA{shoag2010impact} & US State Level & Instrumented on the windfall gains that US states receive from investing public pension funds & Baseline multiplier over 2, rising to over 3 in times of economic slack \\ \hline \citeA{suarez2016estimating} & US County Level & Instrumented on Federal transfers to local counties due to changes in population forecasts between Census and Non-census years & 1.7-2 rising in counties experiencing economic slack \\ \hline \citeA{michaillat2014theory} & US Federal Level & Simple search-and-matching model to highlight the key economic forces of the multiplier & The multiplier doubles when unemployment rises from 5\% to 8\% \\ \hline \citeA{clemens2012} & US State Level & Instrumented on the variation in the strictness states' balanced budget requirements to determine the level as a means of measuring the level of spending cuts during a recession & 0.4 however it may be higher if states receive windfall funding \\ \hline \citeA{Ilzetzki} & 44 countries around the world \footnote{20 high-income and 44 low income} & SVAR approach on a novel dataset & High income countries tend to have a statistically significant positive fiscal multiplier while the opposite is true of developing countries and Investment in infrastructure could lead to a higher multiplier \\ \hline \citeA{acconcia2014mafia} & Italy Local Level & Looked at a situation when local governments were dismissed and public funding was severely reduced in Italy is response to being infiltrated by the mafia.   & 1.5 on impact, growing to 1.9 when dynamic effects are included. \\ \hline \citeA{fishback2015multiplier} & US State Level & Panel of annual Federal expenditure in each State during the 1930s & 0.96 when Federal transfer payments are excluded falling to 0.83 when they are included  \\ 
    \end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```

I would also recommend to use `booktabs` for the horizontal rules (not included in the MWE)

Comment: So I tried doing exactly what you recommended including the  \usepackage{xltabular} however when I compile in Overleaf I'm getting the following error message LaTeX "Error: File `xltabular.sty' not found.

The compiler cannot find the file you want to include. Make sure that you have uploaded the file and specified the file location correctly."  Again forgive my lack of knowledge, but what do I have to do to ensure that Overleaf recognizes this package?